# Twitter4J rawJSON() returning null

Tags: java, json, apache-storm, twitter4j

I'm trying to get the rawJSOn string from a status like:

```
TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status);
```

But its returning null. I did check to see if JSONStoreEnabled() was set to true and it was ( if it weren't I would be get an exception).

Pretty confused at this, as the documentation doesn't describe any possible solutions.

P.S. I did check to see if the Status object I was passing was valid by calling the getText() method and it did return the tweet text.

I'm trying to do this in an Apache Storm bolt which receives a Status object and I use the object as such:

```
Status status = (Status)tuple.getValueByField("tweet");
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the call to `getRawJSON` definitely in the same thread as the call to `createStatus` that originally created it, with no other intervening `create*` calls on that thread in the meantime?

Comment: its on an apache storm topology so the createStatus thread could be called on a different node in the cluster

Comment: Then there's nothing you can do. The `getRawJSON` documentation makes it clear that it only works in limited circumstances - the `Status` object doesn't keep a record of its original JSON, the raw JSON accessor is simply based on the parser keeping a thread-local record of the last thing it parsed, and returning that when asked.

Comment: You'd have to pass the raw JSON instead of the Status object in the tuple and parse it on the worker thread.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I've taken your advice and I'm just passing about the raw JSON string and then recreating a status object at each bolt. Strange however that I need to do this as this is almost the exact same Spout that the examples in the documentation use.

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing similar issues over the last couple of days. I am no expert in the package, however I found that this is an issue with twitter4j version 4.0.3, particularly with:

> twitterObjectFactory.getRawJson(status)

I used the **Twiiter4j 4.0.2 packages** and I was able to retrieve raw json using `DataObjectFactory.getRawJson(status)`. However you will receive a deprecation warning which I chose to ignore.

```
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName()
                    + " - " + status.getText());

            tweetQueue.offer(DataObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. However, after checking the API, I noticed 1 really important sentence:

'Note that raw JSON forms can be retrieved only from the same thread invoked the last method call and will become inaccessible once another method call'

I was trying to integrate the whole thing with Kafka and trying to transform the resultant Status object in a separate method.

I began passing the status to raw json string **inside the onStatus method** itself, like this:

```
@Override
public void onStatus(Status status) {
    queue.offer(TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status));
}
```

And got the issue fixed.